# Kubernetes REST API - Execute a command in container with proper example (java or groovy)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have searched in many places but unable to find one proper way of implementing exec via REST apis(with headers). Can anyone provide an example ?

**Example Usecase:**

I have deployed a mySQL container in kubernetes. I need to create a table in mySQL container using kubernetes REST api. Tried the following,

```
URL url = new URL("https://x.x.x.x:6443/api/v1/namespaces/namespace/pods/podname/exec?container=containername&command=commandtoexecute&stdin=true&stderr=true&stdout=true&tty=true");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection conn= (HttpsURLConnection) con;
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "upgrade");
conn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade", "websocket");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
```

Getting the following error

**Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Comment: The question is not very clear. please take the time to further clarify the question. Try adding an example of what you want to see, or what you thought would work.

Comment: Elaborated the query with an example